# Magento adminnotification_inbox table already exists

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have got a strange error. My magento gives 'adminnotification_inbox' already exists error. I haven't been playing around with adminnotification module but when I removed cache the site went down giving this error.

We changed the db but still we get the same error. Whenever I flush cache the error is displayed for a couple of second and then things go back to normal. I don't know why I am facing this issue.

The code is working on staging server and db has been changed. What could be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Admin panel system -> Notifications  select all notifications and select remove from dropdown it and delete it. refresh cache you will now not get any error.

Comment: Sorry. This didn't work. I am still getting the error.

Comment: disable it from system -> configuration -> advanced -> Mage_adminnotification  disable output and save it and check it.

Comment: Didn't help. Still getting this air on flushing cache: [message:protected] => SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'adminnotification_inbox' already exists. It then disappears after a couple of seconds.